# data.table row filter with another data.table when keys are in a different order

Tags: r, data.table

I'm just learning how to use `data.table` and I'm running into an unexpected issue. I have a large dataset `all` with several indices, 21 columns and ~20K rows. I aggregate `all` grouped by 2 of the indexed columns and name it `fail`. When I attempt to filter the rows of `all` with `fail`, I am only successful if the indices in fail are the first 2 indices in `all`. This is not naturally the case.  How can I tell data.table to ignore the indices in `all` that `fail` does not share?

### test dataset:

```
set.seed(42)
all<-data.table(rep= rep(1:2, each=15, 10), 
                loc= rep(letters[1:15], 20), 
                foo= sample(LETTERS), 
                 x=rnorm(n=300)) 
setkey(all, rep, loc, foo) #note that foo is last instead of 2nd, which would be its desired default position

fail<- all[,sum(x) < -5, by=list(rep,loc)]
setkey(fail, rep,loc)

fail[V1==T]
       rep loc   V1
    1:   2   d TRUE
```

### working filter

```
all[fail[V1==T]]
        rep loc foo           x   V1
     1:   1   f   A -0.46972958 TRUE
     2:   1   f   B  0.18819303 TRUE
     3:   1   f   C -0.65850343 TRUE
     4:   1   f   D -0.88577630 TRUE
     5:   1   f   I  0.08489806 TRUE
     6:   1   f   K -2.44046693 TRUE
     7:   1   f   R -0.43144620 TRUE
     8:   1   f   T  1.81522845 TRUE
     9:   1   f   U -1.01759612 TRUE
    10:   1   f   W -2.11320011 TRUE
```

### non-working filter due to changed index order

```
setkey(all, rep, foo, loc) #foo moved from last to 2nd key
all[fail[V1==T]]
       rep foo loc  x   V1
    1:   2   d  NA NA TRUE
```

Comment: my real `all` dataset has these indices: `rep, mapped, starttime, loc`. This is the desired index order because in *most* use cases `location` is the least important, least searched index. But the `fail` dataset will only ever contain the `rep` and `loc`. Are you telling me that if I want to filter `all` by `fail` I must rekey `all` to suit `fail` before I filter?

Comment: @Arun, data.table_1.9.2 with R 3.0.3 in RStudio on Win7

Comment: @Arun, Apologies. I made a cut and paste error with the working filter output. It's corrected now.  But my issue is that the non-working filter only outputs one line. Your comments and @Jeff 's answer have clarified that this is a limitation of `data.table` and I should use `merge`

Comment: @Arun, so if you do `setkey(all, rep, foo, loc) ` and run `all[fail[V1==T]]` you get 20 rows of output?  I think your confusion is because I put the working example first.  The working key order is *not* the desired default key order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't want to re-key the `all` table (though that would do the trick as well). Does using `data.table::merge` do what you want?

```
merge(all, fail[V1==T], by = c("rep", "loc"))
```

Comment: Before I started using data.table, I was using `merge` with a data.frame. So `merge` does the trick. I just thought that I could speed up the operation using `data.table` syntax

Comment: More recent versions of data.table have a faster implementation of `merge` accessible directly with `data.table::merge`.

Comment: I think the point is that the key on the `all` table changed. Aside from re-keying, this is all I could come up with in terms of a solution.